# Python dataclasses - Enforce attribute type

Tags: python, types, python-dataclasses, python-class

I would like to enforce attribute type in a `dataclass`.

#### Check on init - works

This will prevent the attribute from being set to the wrong type when creating the class instance:

```py
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class FooDC:
    number : int = dataclasses.field(default_factory=int)
    word   : str = dataclasses.field(default_factory=str)

    # Enforce attribute type on init
    def __post_init__(self):
        for field in dataclasses.fields(self):
            value = getattr(self, field.name)
            if not isinstance(value, field.type):
                raise ValueError(f'Expected {field.name} to be {field.type}, '
                                f'got {repr(value)}')

foo = FooDC(word = 2)
```

output

```py
ValueError: Expected word to be <class string>, got 2
```

#### Check on set - does not work

However, I can still set to the wrong output after class instantiation

```py
bar = FooDC()
bar.word = 2
bar.word
```

output

```py
2
```

#### Question

Is there a way to enforce attribute type at all times? I would like to throw an error if I try to set the attribute to the wrong type.

Thank you

Comment: Use a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property). But really, Python is dynamically typed. If you feel like you need this level of type enforcement, Python may not be for you.

Comment: you should consider using [`pydantic`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/)

Comment: Adding to @chepner: And importantly, this level of validation will be *expensive* if you use it everywhere. Statically typed languages pay little or nothing for type validation (the compiler can enforce most of it at compile-time, in the same way that static typing checkers can pre-check Python code for obeying type constraints), but in a dynamically typed language, these checks are at runtime, and the overhead involved in the checks will exceed the actual work done for setting a plain attribute by a significant margin.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `Pydantic`. You will be able to do both, enforce the type at instantiation and afterwards when you want to assign another value to an attribute. With the `validator` method you can check the instantiation like you already had with `dataclasses`. If you use

```
class Config
    validate_assignment = True
```

the types will also be checked if you want to change the attribute `word` afterwards.

The whole code:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class FooDC(BaseModel):
    number: int = 0
    word: str = ""

    @validator('word', pre=True)
    def check_before(cls, v):
        if not isinstance(v, str):
            raise ValueError('must be string')
        return v

    class Config:
        validate_assignment = True
```

This leads to:

```
bar.word = 2
<class 'int'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 380, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__setattr__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for FooDC
word
  must be string (type=value_error)
```

Comment: using a large library like `pydantic` just for simple validation on one or two fields seems a bit of an overkill to me personally.

Comment: This seems like a solution thats more straightforward to implement (in that its a maintained, accessible library). @rv.kvetch, why would it be overkill to use pydantic for just one/two of its features? Would doing affect runtime efficiency or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to add a custom [descriptor class](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#complete-practical-example) which serves as validator, declared as so:

> **Update:** I've also created [a gist](https://gist.github.com/rnag/db6bf83d9ca19dfe897d6ccabd4e2570) for this particular example.

```py
from dataclasses import MISSING
from typing import Callable, Generic, NewType, TypeVar, Union


_NoneType = type(None)
_T = TypeVar('_T')
_UNSET = NewType('_UNSET', None)


class TypeValidator(Generic[_T]):

    __slots__ = ('add_default',
                 'private_name',
                 'default',
                 'default_factory',
                 'type',
                 )

    def __init__(self, *,
                 add_default=True,
                 default: _T = MISSING,
                 default_factory: Callable[[], _T] = MISSING):

        self.add_default = add_default
        self.default = default
        self.default_factory = default_factory

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.private_name = '_' + name

        tp = owner.__annotations__[name]

        try:
            # check for types like `typing.Dict` and `typing.List`.
            tps = tp.__origin__
            # fix for Python 3.7, where `typing.Union` has an `__origin__` attribute
            if tps is Union:
                tps = tp.__args__

        except AttributeError:
            # check for types like `typing.Union[int, str]`
            # and `typing.Optional[float]`.
            tps = getattr(tp, '__args__', tp)

        self.type = tps

        if self.add_default and self.default is self.default_factory is MISSING:
            if isinstance(tps, tuple):  # a tuple of types
                if _NoneType in tps:
                    # if we see a `None` for a type, then `None` is a reasonable
                    # default to use.
                    self.default = None
                    return
                else:
                    # fix, since tuples aren't callable in any case.
                    tps = tps[0]

            # check if the type can be used as a "default factory"
            try:
                _ = tps()
            except TypeError:
                pass
            else:
                self.default_factory = tps

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            # we are called from the `@dataclass` decorator, which processes
            # the class (objtype here).
            return self.default if self.default_factory is MISSING else _UNSET
        # we are called from the class instance, to retrieve the attribute.
        return getattr(obj, self.private_name)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if value is _UNSET:
            value = self.default_factory()
        else:
            self.validate(value)

        setattr(obj, self.private_name, value)

    def validate(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, self.type):
            msg = f'Expected {self.private_name.lstrip("_")} to be {self.type!r}, got {value!r}'
            raise TypeError(msg)
```

And finally, here is how you would use the `TypeValidator` class defined above:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class FooDC:
    # alternatively, like:
    #   number: int = TypeValidator(default_factory=int)
    number: int = TypeValidator()
    word: str = TypeValidator()


foo = FooDC(number=3, word='1')
print(foo)

try:
    _ = FooDC(number='test')
except TypeError as e:
    print(e)
else:
    raise ValueError('expected a TypeError to be raised!')
print()

bar = FooDC()
bar.word = 2
bar.word
```

Out:

```py
FooDC(number=3, word='1')
Expected number to be <class 'int'>, got 'test'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<usr>/loc/my_file.py", line 66, in <module>
    bar.word = 2
  File "/Users/<usr>/loc/my_file.py", line 38, in __set__
    self.validate(value)
  File "/Users/<usr>/loc/my_file.py", line 44, in validate
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: Expected word to be <class 'str'>, got 2
```

#### Complex Type Annotations

The really cool thing about this validator class, is that it works for more complex type annotations, such as [`typing.Dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Dict) and [`typing.Optional`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional). For example:

```py
@dataclass
class FooTest:
    map: dict[str, float] = TypeValidator()
    num_or_str: int | float | str = TypeValidator()
    opt_word: str | None = TypeValidator()


foo = FooTest()
print(foo)

try:
    _ = FooTest(map={'key': 1.23}, num_or_str=b'byte string')
except TypeError as e:
    print(e)
else:
    raise ValueError('expected a TypeError to be raised!')

bar = FooTest()
bar.map = 2
```

In **Python 3.10**, the above code outputs:

```py
FooTest(map={}, num_or_str=0, opt_word=None)
Expected num_or_str to be (<class 'int'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>), got b'byte string'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<usr>/loc/my_file.py", line 104, in <module>
    bar.map = 2
  File "/Users/<usr>/loc/my_file.py", line 72, in __set__
    self.validate(value)
  File "/Users/<usr>/loc/my_file.py", line 79, in validate
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: Expected map to be <class 'dict'>, got 2
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! I hadn't considered using a separate validator class for each assignment. While this is more flexible, I think using Pydantic as a 'built in' mechanism to validate types may cover what I need at the moment.